# C++ undefined reference when calling a function with arrays

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference

I am trying to write a simple code using a minimum of three functions to sort numbers into two arrays, do some calculations and output the results. All of my functions worked when ran altogether in int main, however, when I divided them into functions I am receiving the error message below. I know the issue is with how I am defining or calling my functions, I just cannot figure out what the problem is.

```
clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
/tmp/main-47f1e6.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1df): undefined reference to `GetData(std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

This is one function from my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;




void GetData (ifstream&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&);

int main() {

ifstream inFile; 
int nEven = 0, nOdd = 0;
int number;
int evenArray[30], oddArray[20];
//open file
inFile.open("lab7.txt");
//check file opens
if (!inFile) 
  cout << "Cannot open file, terminating program"<< endl;
else
{
GetData (inFile, number, evenArray[nEven], nEven, oddArray[nOdd], nOdd);
 
inFile.close();

}//end of else
return 0; 
}//end of main

//sort numbers, will not work without cout statements
void GetData (ifstream& inFile, int& number, int (&evenArray)[], int& nEven, int (&oddArray)[], int& nOdd) {
  while(!inFile.eof() && inFile >> number) {
      if (number % 2 == 0) {
        cout << number << "\t";
        evenArray[nEven] = number;
        cout << "even " << evenArray[nEven] << endl;
        nEven += 1;
      }
      else {
        cout << number << "\t";
        oddArray[nOdd] = number;
        cout << "odd " << oddArray[nOdd] <<endl;
        nOdd += 1;
      } //end else 
  } //end of while
}//end Getdata function
return 0;
}//end int main
```

This is sample data:

```
46 30 82 90 56 17 95 16 48 26
4 58 0 78 92 60 12 21 63 47
19 41 90 85 14 -9 52 71 79 16
80 51 95 102 34 10 79 95 61 92
89 88 66 18 6 63 66 64 39 5
```

Comment: "_This is my complete code:_" - Why is it your complete code? Haven't you managed to narrow the problem down at all? First, remove unused variables from your [mre]: Example: [lots of unused](https://godbolt.org/z/c5ohhE)

Comment: I got rid of two of the functions since it is the same error for all of them. I have isolated the error to how I am calling or defining functions but I do not know what my mistake is.

Comment: The program does however not compile.

Comment: You declare `GetData` with one signature and you define it with a different signature.

Comment: I am new to C++, Can you please explain what you mean by different signatures?

Comment: `GetData()` is declared before `main()` with one signature (set of argument types, and return type). Calling `GetData()` in `main()` therefore needs a `GetData()` with THAT signature to be defined. The`GetData()` that is defined after `main()` has a different signature.   For example, the third argument in the declaration before `main()` has type `int &`, but the third argument in the function definition after `main()` has type `int (&evenArray)[]` - which is not the same as `int &`  (In fact, `int (&evenArray)[]` is not even a valid type, so fails to compile - contrary to your description).